# Local variables for a class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have noticed the following code is syntactically correct:

```
class Foo
  bar = 3
end
```

Now, I know that instance variables are accessed by `@`, and class variables by `@@`, but I couldn't figure out where `bar` is stored in this case or how to access it.

How can I find `bar`'s scope?

Comment: It's a local variable just like any other local variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The body of a class in Ruby is just executable Ruby code. These are indeed local variables (no quotation needed) and follow the *"regular"* rules being local variables. You can access them in the body of the class. If you literally want the scope where `bar` is defined, you can use [`Kernel.binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-binding):

```
class Foo
  bar = 42

  @@scope = binding

  def self.scope
    @@scope
  end  
end 

Foo.scope.local_variables          # => [:bar]
Foo.scope.local_variable_get(:bar) # => 42
```

A thing to note - using `def` changes the scope, therefore, they won't be visible inside methods defined using `def`.

Answer (score 7):

It is accessible from the same class body.

```
class Foo
  bar = 3
  bar # => 3
end
```

It is lexically scoped, so it is accessible from within a block:

```
class Foo
  bar = 3
  pr = ->{p bar}
  pr.call # => 3
end
```

but it is not accessible even in the same class once the class body has been closed:

```
class Foo
  bar = 3
end
class Foo
  bar # => error 
end
```

nor can it be accessed from within a method definition:

```
class Foo
  bar = 3
  def baz; bar end
  new.baz # => error
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The `bar` variable will be accessible until you close the definition of the class. It will not be accessible inside the methods you define.

You can try to run the code in irb:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> class Test
irb(main):002:1> bar = 1
irb(main):003:1> puts bar
irb(main):004:1> end
1
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> puts bar
NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for main:Object
        from (irb):5
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):006:0> class Test
irb(main):007:1> puts bar
irb(main):008:1> end
NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for Test:Class
        from (irb):7:in `<class:Test>'
        from (irb):6
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):009:0>
```

Check for the availability in the instance methods:

```
irb(main):018:0> class Test
irb(main):019:1> bar = 1
irb(main):020:1> def test
irb(main):021:2> puts bar
irb(main):022:2> end
irb(main):023:1> end
=> :test
irb(main):024:0> a = Test.new
=> #<Test:0x00000000f447a0>
irb(main):025:0> a.test
NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for #<Test:0x00000000f447a0>
        from (irb):21:in `test'
        from (irb):25
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Check for availability in the class methods:

```
irb(main):026:0> class Test
irb(main):027:1> bar = 1
irb(main):028:1> def self.test
irb(main):029:2> puts bar
irb(main):030:2> end
irb(main):031:1> end
=> :test
irb(main):032:0> Test.test
NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for Test:Class
        from (irb):29:in `test'
        from (irb):32
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is there a way to "save" this declarations? A way to propagate them onto a method or something?

Comment: @GiladNaaman: nope. Hence the name, _local_ variable. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a constant and use it instance and class methods:

```
class Foo
    Bar = 3

    def local_bar(param = Bar)
        param
    end
end

p Foo.new.local_bar
#=> 3
```